# Eclipse error: The type org.eclipse.emf.edit.domain.EditingDomain cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, resources, emf, diffmerge

I've got an error message in Eclipse:

```
The type org.eclipse.emf.edit.domain.EditingDomain cannot be resolved.
It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I've got it when I tried to use the EMF DiffMerge plugin on my EMF model project. I loaded an instance model of my project from an EMF persisted XMI file to a Resource and tried to gave it to EMF DiffMerge like this (the error is given on the last line):

```
ResourceSet resSet = new ResourceSetImpl();

Resource resource = resSet.getResource(URI.createURI("grafok/MyGraph.xmi"),true);
IEditableModelScope targetScope = new FragmentedModelScope(resource);
```

Can you help guys what's the problem?

Anyway I tried cleaning the project and remove the JRE library and add it again in the properties/Java build path, as advised in another similar post but these didnt help.

Comment: is the `org.eclipse.emf.edit.domain` plugin in your dependencies?

Comment: I'm not sure about it because I'm not sure if I check it at the right place. Could you verify that where should I check it?

Comment: open your Manifest.MF file and switch to view dependencies, click on add and insert `org.eclipse.emf.edit`, adding this plugin may resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `org.eclipse.emf.transaction` to the dependencies of your project. 
That will solve you problem.